# want to give access for many organsation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are developing a online rails application for schools, but we want to separate that all schools to each other. 
Like [slack](https://slack.com/) website that manage many organisation from one application and organisation only access that data.
Also like [trello](https://trello.com/), they also separate organisations in one application.

So what is the best approach is use for such type of application?

How we implement this in our ruby on rails application,that we separate all schools in our Database?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.

**Multi Tenancy**

If you're coming from the world of "native" software, you'll be best reading up on [*multi tenancy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy):

[image]
<sub>(source: [theenterprisearchitect.eu](http://www.theenterprisearchitect.eu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/100427_multi-tenancy_and_mde_necessary_assests_of_a_paas.png))</sub>

Rails apps are multi tenant by virtue of them running through a network; they run a single instance of an app, which is then accessible to anyone on that network (remember, the Internet is a huge network).

Rails provides all the functionality you mentioned above, with the added benefit of having a lot of world-leading companies using it to run (Twitter, AirBnb, Groupon etc have all famously used Rails).

You need to read up on database system design for your application, specifically...

---

**MVC**

To better understand how you'd make an application like you referenced, you need to understand the [MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller) programming pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and it's value within the world of [object-orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) system design, especially pertaining to Rails:

[image]

Rails, like many other frameworks, uses MVC to build *objects*. These objects are defined by the programmer, but basically allow you to create the relevant data required to provide functionality to an application like you mentioned.

Specifically, each time you *access* a Rails app - you'll be essentially manipulating *objects* filled with data from the db. I'll explain any specifics in an update if you need it.

In regards your question, the way to integrate multiple organizations/entities into a single application is to set up the database schema to manage the `organization` as the "parent", with users and data as extra elements:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_many :invoices
   has_many :clients, through: :invoices
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   has_many :invoices
end

#app/models/invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :clients
end
```

This will give you the ability to use something like the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints Account do
   root "invoices#index" #-> http://company.url.com
   resources :invoices #-> http://company.url.com/invoices/3
end

#lib/account.rb
class Account
   def matches?(request)
      Company.exists?(request.subdomain)
   end
end
```

You'd then be able to use [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to sign the user into the organization, allowing them to add / edit `invoices` as they need.

Each time you edit or update an invoice, a `user` will be assigned to it, allowing you to determine who created it etc.

Without going deeper into the code, that's what I think you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

As concern of database design, you can design something like:

You should manage a organization model where each organization must be a sub-domain and your other model like User etc.. should be associate with organization model.You can extract the subdomain name from request url (like request.host, request.subdomain etc..) and find the records as per this subdomain request.

As concern of resource permission you can use cancan gem where you can manage resource accessibility through a single file.

```
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan
```

Hope it is helpful for your initial design.